# Trigger by suffix from same element class

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, correlation, prefix

I want make every button which have suffix class `-dummy` (let's call it "dummy") to trigger another button who have same class but without that suffix (call it "real button").

`<button class="btn-submit hidden">` triggered by `<button class="btn-submit-dummy">`

`<button class="btn-edit hidden">` triggered by `<button class="btn-edit-dummy">`

`<button class="btn-delete">` triggered by nothing since there is no element with class `btn-delete-dummy`

Each real button need to be triggered by click on the dummy.

My script so far :

```
/** If I define manually on each button **/
$(".btn-submit-dummy").click(function() {
    $(".btn-submit").trigger("click");
});
$(".btn-edit-dummy").click(function() {
    $(".btn-edit").trigger("click");
});
...
...
...
/** end of defining button **/
```

My idea if written in jQuery and human language (sorry for this ugly way) as the following :

```
$("button[class$='-dummy']").click(function() {
    var realButton = button_which_have_same_class_as_clicked_object_but_trimmed_with_"-dummy";
    if(find realButton) {
        $(realButton).trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$("[class$='-dummy']").on('click', function () {
    var btnClass = $(this).attr('class').match(/([\w-]+-dummy)+/)[0].replace('-dummy', '');

    alert(btnClass);
    $("." + btnClass).trigger("click");
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/gc3d5yy5/

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah thanks.. Almost complete.. Just change `button.show` to `[class$='-dummy']` and works decently..

Answer (score 0):

You can call click event by

```
$("[class$=-dummy]").on('click',function(e){
   var a = ($(this).attr('class');
   var fire = a.replace('-dummy"','');
   $('.'+fire).trigger('click');
});
```